# Can't figure out class ordering in precision_recall_fscore_support return values in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

After numerous tries, I can't understand the way one can recover the classes metrics from [`precision_recall_fscore_support`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html) return values.

For example, given this classical learning context:

```
target_names = set(y)
y = [target_names.index(x) for x in y]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

# Some classification ...

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
precision, recall, f1, support = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, y_pred)
```

Here, `len(set(y_test)) == len(support)` so I imagine that all classes present in `y_test` are present in the return values. But I can't find the way they are ordered, so I can recover which metrics correspond to which class.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The labels are in sorted order. [Quoting the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html) :-

> By default, all labels in y_true and y_pred are used in sorted order

The order of classes is decided by the `labels` parameter in `precision_recall_fscore_support`. If not supplied any, then the default behaviour is to collect all classes in `y_pred` and `y_true` and arranged in sorted order.

Documentation Example:

```
y_true = np.array(['cat', 'pig', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'pig'])
y_pred = np.array(['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog'])

precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred)
```

Output:

```
(array([ 0.66666667,  0.        ,  0.        ]),
 array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]),
 array([ 0.8,  0. ,  0. ]),
 array([2, 2, 2]))
```

The above tuple have 4 arrays (precision, recall, f_score and support) and each array has 3 elements, one each for 'cat', 'dog' and 'pig'. (As you can yourself calculate that the metrics are arranged according to sorted classes 'cat', 'dog', 'pig').

Even if you change the order of labels here:-

```
y_true = np.array(['cat', 'dog', 'pig', 'cat', 'dog', 'pig'])
y_pred = np.array(['cat', 'pig', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog'])
```

the output will be same:-

```
(array([ 0.66666667,  0.        ,  0.        ]),
 array([ 1.,  0.,  0.]),
 array([ 0.8,  0. ,  0. ]),
 array([2, 2, 2]))
```

Same happens if `y` have numerical values.

Hope it clears your doubts. Feel free to ask any doubt.